# PyQt: QStandardItemModel: How to get a row as a list?

Tags: qt, pyqt

How can I get the row from the model?
Is it really necessary to go through the row and get step by step each item?

I am using this function, it is working, but I am not really satisfied with that.
Is there better way how to do it?

```
def row(self, r):               
    row = []
    for c in range(self.columnCount()):
        index = self.index(r, c)
        value = self.data(index).toString()
        row.append(value)        
    return row
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting all into a list comprehension:

```
row = [self.data(self.index(r,c))
       for c in xrange(self.columnCount())]
```

is probably faster, though of course not really nicer to read.

If you want to use the models provided by Qt - then yes, it's the only way to access the underlying data.

You could use a `QStandardItemModel`, which would allow you to do

```
row = [self.item(r,c) for c in xrange(self.columnCount())]
```

which only avoids the need to create the index though.

Depending on your use case, you could of course implement generic Qt models based on Python lists or dicts that would allow access items in the Qt way and in the python way.